# updating file in distributed cache in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, updates, distributed-cache

How can we update file/files in distributed cache?.

For instance I have a properties file in distributed cache Now I have added few more values in properties file.

**Options:**

1. Append new values in old file and restart the job.
2. Replace the old file with new one and restart the job.
3. Place the new file in new location and point to that location.

Which all above options are correct and Why ?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What kind of properties? What are you trying to do? Do you want to update the file, while the job is running with new values (I don't think you can do that)? Do you want to start a new job with a file in the Distributed Cache that has changed from a previous job?

Answer (score 0):

This requires an understanding of how distributed cache works:
When you add a file to distributed cache, at the time of running the job the file is copied to each task node and that file is available locally. Since it creates multiple copies : It cannot be modified.

Option 2 & 3 sound feasible but not sure if that is the right way.

If the file just has a bunch of properties you can set these in the configuration object instead of file in distributed cache. You could use the collector to write the output to the desired location. (I do not know your use case clearly so this may not be suitable).